# I have two functions in one controller I need to use on one route or i want to call func in other func

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel-5.4

```
public function anasayfa() //this is my first func
{
  $rastgele = Anime::inRandomOrder()->take(7)->get();
  foreach ($rastgele as $random) {
    $random->adi = substr($random->adi, 0,18);
  }
  $son = Anime::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(7)->get(); // select * from animes orderby created_at dec limit 7
  foreach ($son as $anime) {
    $anime->adi = substr($anime->adi, 0,18);
  }

  return view('anasayfa',compact('rastgele','son'));
}
Route::get('/','AnimeController@anasayfa'); // this is route 
public function bolumler($id) // this is second function
{
  $episode = Anime::find($id)->bolumler;
  return view('anasayfa',compact('episode'));
}
```

I want to call second func like `Route::get('/','AnimeController@bolumler');`
but cannot how can do this, second function giving each animes all episodes first function giving some animes name and image URL if I cannot with same route how can I? okey we can not use same route but if i can call anasayfa func in bolumler func?

Comment: You need to either change the path or method for the second `Route`. Otherwise youll have a duplicate.

Comment: you cannot use same route for all 
try this `Route::get('/{id}','AnimeController@bolumler');  ` 

and you can call `domain.com/15`   (15 here is your id)